# Changing a struct with one type to another type

Tags: swift, swift4

I have two structs with the same fields. What is the best way to merge them.

```
struct Type1{
    var variable1:String?    
    var variable2:Double?
    var variable3:String?

    var notImporant:String?
} 

struct Type2{
    var variable1A:String?    
    var variable2A:String?
    var variable3A:String!
}
```

What is the best way to convert `type2` to `type1`? I am getting a return from an API and parsing it using codable but there are two different structs and I need to get one struct. The data is the same, it is just mapped differently in terms of types. Some of the structs have more info and others have less.

Comment: Actually the structs do **not** contain the same *fields*

Comment: they might be different types but the values are similar for example price will  always be price whether it is an int or a string. I am not talking about them having the same field but for all intents and purposes they are the same

Comment: give one an initializer that takes the other as parameter

Comment: yes, like the answer below right?

Comment: yes, I've edited his answer to make it a bit clearer: that would allow you to say `let t2 = Type2(t1)` — that is not casting, it is _coercion_

Answer (score 6):

Just make a copy constructor in both structs like so:

```
struct Type2 {
  var variable1A:String?    
  var variable2A:String?
  var variable3A:String!
  init(_ otherType: Type1) {
    variable1A = otherType.variable1
    variable2A = otherType.variable2
    variable3A = otherType.variable3
  }
}
```

Comment: `otherType.variable2` needs to be converted.

Comment: @PhillipMills sharp eye, feel free to edit my edit :)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot cast two unrelated structs. What you can do is define a common Protocol for the two of them, and use them in places where you don't care which underlying object it is.

```
protocol CommonProtocol {
    var variable1: String? { get }
    var variable3: String? { get }
}

struct Type1: CommonProtocol {

    var variable1:String?    
    var variable2:Double?
    var variable3:String?

    var notImporant:String?
} 

struct Type2: CommonProtocol {

    var variable1A:String?    
    var variable2A:String?
    var variable3A:String!

}
```

Then, in whichever place you're currently stuck with a `type1` instead of a `type2`, have that function just accept a `CommonProtocol` instead, and you can use either.

Note that, while both of your types have a `variable2`, one of them is a `Double?` while the other is a `String?`. There are a few different ways to approach that, which I leave to you. I just left it out of the protocol.

On another note, it's Swift standard to capitalize the names of structs (`Type1`, `Type2`). In certain instances, you can run into problems if you don't, so I suggest you do.

Comment: can this be using with codable? the whole reason that I have to do this is because I am using codable.

Comment: Definitely. It depends on your importing logic if you'll need to change anything. If you're able to _instantiate_ everything as a concrete type (`Type1`, `Type2`), then just keep it the way it is. If you want to _instantiate_ something from JSON that might be _either_ a `Type1` or `Type2`, you will need an extra field in your JSON that tells you which type it is. Then you can initialize it via Codable as before.